# Httpclient not returning entire response

Tags: java, httpclient

Using HttpClient 4.0, Im having an issue where the response I get from the `ResponseHandler` is only about half of what the actual page content should be (~61k bytes in the string vs ~125k in the page returned to a browser). I cant seem to find any place where there might be some sort of limit that would limit this. Any ideas?

Update: One other thing I have found is that the size returned by the entity's `getContentLength` method is -1, whereas it is a normal value for the previous request. The javadoc seems to indicate that means the length is unknown- Any ideas why that might be the case?

Update2: I tried finding a response for a page more than 80KB. Its interesting that maximum length of the response string is always 18210 characters. Any ideas??

Comment: Have you looked at the response content?  Are you are getting a truncated version of the page you are expecting ... or a different page?

Comment: A truncated version-literally the first half of the page.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be it, but sometimes this can happen if you aren't flushing a stream somewhere.

Comment: Agreed. Especially if System.exit() is called when Threads are involved with the I/O.

Comment: This might be it-can you elaborate? The `DefaultHttpClient` that fetches that page also fetches 6+ before. Do I need to be explicitly flushing/clearing something?

Comment: I think you just need to be sure not to exit while there is still data left to read. Have a look at the javadoc http://goo.gl/iJjd with respect to closing the stream and javadoc for InputStream.available() http://goo.gl/qXUf

Answer (score 1):

I found that this was caused by me calling `client.getConnectionManager().shutdown()` BEFORE reading the response.  I had goofed up one of my `finally {}` blocks when doing the request, and the shutdown was causing a race condition which would sometimes kill the response mid-read.

It just so happened that `getContentLength()` was returning -1 for me as well, which was caused by the Transfer-Encoding: chunked header.  I had assumed that the HttpClient library wasn't dealing with the chunked response correctly, but really it was just my goof up.

Answer (score 0):

The other place you should look is on the server side.

One possibility is that the webapp code is occasionally throwing a wobbly halfway through writing the response.  Another is that there's a bug in the server container code.  For instance, I vaguely recall that there was a bug in some older versions of Tomcat that caused large responses to be mangled / truncated.